# how to make adjustpan and scrollview working in android

Tags: android, scrollview, adjustpan

how to make `adjustpan` and `scrollview` working  in android.

I have tried adjust thee size but it still shifts my image a little bit. Not completely when I used `fillviewport` and match `paren`. I wo have tried all the reference questions and dint get much help.

I would really appreciate some help!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  If you show us the code that is not working we will be able to help.  At present this is impossible because we do not know how or why the problem has occurred.

Comment: Thank you !! i have used adjustpan in manifest file and it just doesnt let me scroll any other view in the activity. So my initial question is can i scroll my view if i provide adjustpan in my manifest file in android.

Comment: @Simon does it make sense ?

Comment: Unfortunately I know little about Android but I am is trying to get your question answered as quickly as possible without down-votes.   The comment I made above meant that you should include the code you used to try and scroll with in your manifest file code.